# how to get element nightwatchjs

Tags: html, nightwatch.js

i'm very newbie for this topic.i want to use waitForElementPresent,

```
      <a class="qa-header-tjk" href="javascript:;">TJK</a>

       module.exports={
       tags:['bilyoner login'],
       'Bilyoner Login Test' :function (browser){
       browser
       .url('www.bilyoner.com')
       .waitForElementPresent('.qa-header-tjk',100);

       }

      };
```

but it doesnt work. it returns Timed out while waiting for element <.qa-header-tjk> to be present for 100 milliseconds.  - expected "found" but got: "not found".

But i couldnt find a solution. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your timeout is too small ,the default timeout is 500ms so you should set timeout greater than 500ms instead of 100ms.100ms is not enough for loading page.

instead of

`.waitForElementPresent('.qa-header-tjk',100);`

You should try

```
.waitForElementPresent('a[class=qa-header-tjk]',1000);
```